# How to run 2 jmx JMETER SCRIPT in non GUI Mode

Tags: jmeter, jmx

I have a scenerio in which I have to run 2 jmeter script test1.jmx and test2.jmx script in Non Gui Mode
in windows. Please help me as I have only one script runing idea. like jmeter -n -t -l.
etc
please help me.

I have tried with jmeter -n -t -t but it just runing one script and I hav to run 2 scripts paralle in non gui mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your operating system scripting mechanisms to start 2 instances of JMeter in parallel.

Alternatively you can use [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/), it supports JMeter existing tests execution, once you [install Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/) you should be able to do something like:

```
bzt your-script-1.jmx your-script-2.jmx
```

and Taurus will run both tests in parallel.

More information: [The Complete Taurus Course](https://www.blazemeter.com/university/complete-taurus-course)

Comment: Can you let me know How Can I run on windows operating system?

Comment: Create a batch file with 2 lines like                                        
`start "test1" cmd /c "jmeter.bat -n -t test1.jmx" 
start "test2" cmd /c "jmeter.bat -n -t test2.jmx"` Each `start` command needs to be on the separate line

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion\help. In my case I run the batch as following succefully.
Remember my jmeter installed on D drive. Batch script are as just run for the exact command by making a batch file without brackets(       

start D:\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t D:\jmeterfolder\test1.jmx -l D:\jmeterfolder\result1.csv
start D:\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t D:\jmeterfolder\test2.jmx -l D:\jmeterfolder\result2.csv)
START NEED TO BE ON SEPARTE LINE BE CAREFUL ABOUT IT.